# If $(a,b)\sim(A,B)$ and $(c,d) \sim (C,D)$ prove $(a,b)*(c,d)\sim(A,B)*(C,D)$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations, integers

If $(a,b) \sim (A,B)$ and $(c,d) \sim (C,D)$, where all pairs are whole numbers,

Prove that: $(a,b)*(c,d)\sim(A,B)*(C,D)$

Relation defined on the following:

$(a,b)\sim (A,B) \iff a+B=A+b$

$(c,d)\sim(C,D) \iff c+D=C+d$

For this I am assume we have to work a little backwards to show the proof, any tips on how to go about this.

$(a,b)+(c,d)=(a+c, b+d)$ and $(a,b)*(c,d)=(ac+bd, ad+bc)$

Comment: You forgot to  define the relation $\sim\ \ $

Comment: Could you define your symbols a bit more? $~$ is a general binary relation and it makes me nervous to interpret $*$ willy-nilly in that case.

Comment: @BillDubuque that is what I pointed out to my professor, but as he explained we can assume the old material we learned in the sense that (a,b)~(c,d)=(a+c, b+d) and (a,b)*(c,d)=(ac+bd, ad+bc) is all we covered in this class....So I am stuck trying prove the above question. Any idea on what I should do thanks!

Comment: @KitterCatter * as in multiply on my exam question its a dot slightly higher then the middle, the assumption I made along with my class mates is that he meant multiply.

Comment: It appears that you are constructing the integers as differences of naturals, is that correct?  Thus $(a,b)\sim(A,B)\iff  a+B = A+b,\,$ correct?

Comment: @BillDubuque yes that is correct.

Comment: You need to add that context to your question since it is impossible infer otherwise.

Comment: Added, thanks for the suggestion. This may actually help me more the fact that I needed that information myself.

Comment: @JamesMcNoir Don't forget to include the definition of the $*$ operator.

Comment: Some related questions:
[Showing the consistency of an equivalence relation over *](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/636276),
[Show that multiplication $[(x, y)] * [(n,m)] = [(xn + ym, xm + yn)]$ is also well-defined](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1542353),
[Definition of multiplication intuition (Set theory)](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1175248), 
[Equivalence Relations and Equivalence Classes](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/208796).

Comment: They were found using Approach0 - I tried
[this query](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24(a%2Cb)*(c%2Cd)%3D(ac%2Bbd%2C%20ad%2Bbc)%24&p=1)
and [this query](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24(ac%2Bbd%2C%20ad%2Bbc)%24%2C%20integers&p=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice:

$(a,b)~(A,B)⟹ a+B=b+A ⟹ B-A=b-a$ This ending will call **

$(c,d)~(C,D)⟹ c+D=d+C ⟹ c-d=C-D$ This ending will call **

Use ** so that we get: $(C-D)(B-A)=(c-d)(b-a)$

Foil:

$BC+AD-AC-BD=bc-ad-ac+ad$

Rearrange the terms to get: $ac+bd+AD+BC=ad+bc+AC+BD$

Which is $(ac+bd,ad+bc)~(AC+BD,AD+BC)$

$(a,b)*(c,d)~(A,B)(C,D)$

As we needed to prove.

Answer (score 2):

If you already know that $\sim$ is equivalence relation, then it suffices to show that 
$$(a,b) \sim (A,B) \implies (a,b)\ast(c,d) \sim (A,B)\ast(c,d). \tag{1}$$

Once you have this, you can get also $(a,b)\ast(c,d)\sim(A,B)\ast(c,d)$ using transitivity of $\sim$ and commutativity of $\ast$.

---

So to prove (1) we assume that $(a,b)\sim(A,B)$, i.e., that $a+B=A+b$. And we try to say something about $(ac+bd,ad+bc)$ and $(Ac+Bd,Ad+Bc)$.

We get
$$(ac+bd) + (Ad+Bc) = (a+B)c+(A+b)d = (A+b)c+(a+B)d = (Ac+Bd)+(ad+bc)$$
which is exactly
$$(ac+bd,ad+bc)\sim(Ac+Bd,Ad+Bc).$$

---

It is worth mentioning that this is equivalence relation is often used to [construct integers from natural numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer#Construction). Which is a reason why it is better to avoid using subtraction in the proof - we assume that only operation which was defined so far.

We can embed [cancellative commutative semigroup into a group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/79453/when-a-semigroup-can-be-embedded-into-a-group) using a similar approach.

Comment: Beat me to finishing it up. I like the second link thanks for a good read!

Answer (score 0):

You only need to prove $ac+bd-AC-BD=ad+bc-AD-BC$, so you only need to prove
$a(c-d)+A(D-C) +b(d-c)+B(C-D)=0$, left is equal to $(a-b)(c-d)+(A-B)(D-C)$
Clearly it is zero, since $A-a=B-b, C-c=D-d$

Comment: mind explaining how you derive the first equation you have gotten.